# C++ Class that has multiple names

Tags: c++, class

```cpp
class Color
{
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
};
```

I've created a class like above, and I would like to be able to use the same class using 'Colour' as an alternative of this class like below.

```cpp
Colour c;
```

Would there be a way to create this simply?

Comment: May I ask why you want to have two names for a class, especially when they differ in language? It's possible this is somehow an x/y problem.

Comment: Do you want instances of Color and Colour to be interchangeable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might create alias:

```
using Colour = Color;
```

Comment: While technically correct, I am afraid, this answer steers OP in the wrong direction :(

Comment: @SergeyA Having both variants of a spelling seems reasonable enough for a name.